# What is an efficient way of moving home?

Tags: appliances, new-home

I have been moving so many times in the past few years, usually on my own without any help. It’s exhausting and painful. I’ve probably become more efficient over time but I’m still trying to figure things out and the fear of next move scared me to death while I’m unpacking in the new place for a couple of months now!

I usually keep all the boxes for appliances from the grater and teapot to that exercise thing, etc. I have been wondering if it would be more efficient and less time consuming if I get rid of all these boxes and pack/move them only by wrapping clothes around them? The concern about that approach is that then clothes would be mixed up with kitchen items and separating them would also be time consuming.

1. Should I keep the boxes or not?
2. How do you move and what tips do you have to ease of the pain of this process?

Comment: I minimize volume by packing things inside things : packing china (suitably wrapped) inside the microwave etc etc...

Comment: If you move frequently just  get a caravan and save on rent

Comment: @DDS fun fact? I have a camper van, but even though I have managed living minimally in it for months, it’s not feasable in long term when you have a job in a city and all the issues around safety, where to park it and even feeling not having enough head space at times...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about home improvement and it's too broad.

Comment: Why are you moving so often? That's the real problem to solve.

Comment: @isherwood is there a way I could improve it to fit, or post it in another SE site?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft that’s somewhat solved for now, but I realize I won’t be in this rental place forever and need to move again in some years max. How to be efficient is the topic.

Comment: Lifehacks.se?   But this is largely a psychological problem: getting better at moving can only do so much to cure *dread of moving* or *dissatisfaction with ones transience*.  Oh one other thing: if you're in metropolitan UK: **narrowboat**/continuous cruise.  It's like #vanlife, but so very much classier.

Comment: @Harper have you tried any of those? My reasons for moving were out of my control: accommodation provided by work which meant they had nowhere permanent, so quitting was the best option and so on. It is psychological to a good extent I believe. Sometimes life gets tough...

Comment: I follow people on social media who do that sort of thing. The dread is the bulk of it, the doing is just doing.

Comment: While it might not apply as much to frequent moves, where you may legitimately not have opened up stuff from the previous move, I know people who move after 10 years or more in one place and find unopened boxes. Clutter can be a **huge** part of the problem. When you make the next move, seriously consider tossing - and then replacing if needed later - items that you haven't used in > 2 years. "Sentimental" only goes so far when you have to keep moving it around - take pictures and then toss (or Freecycle, etc. - many times other can make use of your excess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The #1 asset of any frequent mover is a **[private mail box](https://www.upstudionc.com/blogs/news/lessons-learned-ups-mailbox-vs-po-box)** or PMB such as the UPS Store.  **It means you always get your mail**.  I know many people who don't use PMBs and have nasty tax bills, credit burns *and even arrest warrants (on failure to appear)*  because a trivial problem festered into a bad one.  The DMV, the IRS, banks, creditors, all exclusively use **postal mail** for anything timely or urgent.

It is simply impossible to contact *everyone* every time you move - seriously, who remembers the IRS or the SSA?

PMBs are pricey but they work. Everyone accepts PMBs.  The PMB can receive UPS or FedEx *and even sign for you*.  You can reach a human, give credit card # and they'll **forward your mail anywhere in the world**. Sometimes I just have them mail mine if I don't have time to go over there. They'll call you if you get a certified letter.

Even *at-the-house* utilities like the gas company, always tell them to send your mail to the PMB, which they will cheerfully do. **That means you get your last statement**.

Life just works so much better with a PMB.

---

Granted, I just spent a lot of time on your second question.

On your first question, it's real simple: hoard quality knockdown boxes, like Bankers Boxes or better.  Those are for your stuff.  If it's easy and you have the space, sure, *why not* save original boxes.  I don't work that hard at it, unless the appliance is delicate and likely to take damage in shipping (NOT a microwave).

*That said, the custom shipping foam blocks are the only thing that makes the box worth saving. I often see people with a coffeemaker set in the bottom of its original box, with the foams missing or thrown away. That defeats the purpose of saving the box; the coffeemaker won't be protected from damage anymore than in any other box.  So why keep a weird box around?*

Moving is just a lot of packing and 1000 trips to the car.  That's just what it is.  If you are sick of it, hire out the "1000 trips to the car" job to some "two guys and a truck" type operation, that's not so expensive, you don't have to go full Mayflower.

Comment: Thanks Harper. The post isn’t an issue, I have that sorted. But the 1000 trips and everything else is. I had never thought of the man and van option till after I moved here. I may use them next time even though i have a van myself, but I don’t know if they’d do the packing for me. Sometimes I feel so helpless just by the thoughts to a level I find it tough to keep going!

Comment: + for the P.O. box , after my last move some of our mail was getting returned from the VA, caused some problems that took months to get corrected. I think this would be a good idea for someone that moves often.

Comment: Don't simply hoard quality boxes; go out and buy some. If you're in or near a large metro area there will probably be a packaging distributor or manufacturer selling them locally, and at better quality than you'll find in a "big-box" office supply or general retail store. Buy one size for books and other heavy objects (sized so that its fully-filled weight is manageable) and another larger size for lighter objects. Double-wall is worth the price. When you have 20 boxes (or whatever number, depending on household size) that are all the same type they stack easily and neatly into the moving van.

Comment: @GregHill The office-moving boxes I use are made to use many times and [look like this](http://www.cds-usa.com/Products/CDS-Moving-Equipment/Boxes/Moving-Boxes?ItemID=722). They go from "stored" to "ready" with the flick of a wrist. No tape; no fold-n-tuck. Even Bankers Boxes pale by comparison.  I have never seen them in any retail store.  Once you've had those, you can't go back... common boxes are just annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Boxes:  So far the cheapest place I've found is ULine.
Figure out a set of boxes that are common multiples.  It is *so* much easier to stack them.
E.g. One standard box is 12x12x15.  We have a lot of books and correspondence.  These are close enough to banker's boxes.  So 18 x 12 x 15 is a good size.  as is 24 x 12 x 15.  The first 3 of it fits wehre 2 of #1 fits.  The second is just twice as big.  6 x 24 x 30 makes a good size for pictures.

Pallets:  If you get a bunch of pallets you can pack from your house into your garage.  Pallets aren't really necessary if your garage is dry, but it allows you to use a pallet jack to move the stacks around.

Seacan:  Consider buying a seacan.  I priced a move recently.  To move a seacan 1500 km was going to cost me $2500.  To move my household would have been $12,000.  Upside of this:  Packing can be more drawn out.  You don't have to do it all today.  Downside:  You have to live without X longer, and you can't blame the moving company for breakage.

Write a  clue on every box.  For me the best one is where it was.  E.g. SB Desk: L Drawers or Kit. Under sink

Set aside some things that can be used as filler -- things you don't really care when you unpack them but you can slot into boxes that aren't full.  Extra bedding, pillows for large boxes, books, CDs for smaller boxes.

We keep one drawer in the laundry room that has the manual for everything.  Be sure this ends up in ONE box.

Answer (score 0):

Do what the professionals do; Get moving boxes. Throwaway your original mixed size boxes ,I never saw a major appliance put into a box to move ( professionals have moved me 4 times- company moves.). Moving boxes ( eg. U-Haul) are standard sizes that work well together. After the move break them down flat and save them if you think you will need them again. I have not bothered to box everything like the pros ( eg, arm chairs, full wastebaskets, etc) but as much as possible. Lots of newspaper for dishware. Wardrobe boxes for hanging clothes. Do not fill any box with heavy stuff like books. Clean out junk first , and things like open food containers. Rent a bigger truck or trailer than you think you need, you will fill it.

Comment: Because fitting it into the foam packaging **takes time**.  Any pro mover caught fiddle-diddling with that would be fired on the spot. They're paid by the box and motion is everything. You have the item and original carton, item goes in 1 box, carton goes in another, BOOM they sold you 2 boxes and charged you to move 2. Instead of 0 and 1.  If you wanted the factory protection, you have to pack it yourself.

Comment: I totally agree with you on that @Harper.My dad has always helped the whole family with packing. He takes his time and packs them in such a perfect way. Sadly I'm in a different continent and can't get his help! I can't justify how strangers could pack my stuff for me?! On a side note someone introduced "The Life Changing Magic of Tidying Up" by Marie Kondo yesterday, and only listening to the first2chapters I managed to tidy up the bedroom & two of the boxes for which I had been struggling for months! I believe that will help with the next move as well!

Comment: But again, I guess it's the usual trade off of time and money; either spend the time and do it yourself and save up money, or spend money and get someone do it for you (and get frustrated by the quality if you have high standards) and save up time...